# iOS: animate UICollectionView vertical expansion with constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, constraints

I've a view controller with a UICollectionView on top (using the default grid layout) followed by other controls below it. As I add / remove cells to / from the collection view, I want it to expand / contract in the vertical direction (so it has enough rows to show all of the cells and no more), and all controls below it to move down / up the screen accordingly. If you imagine how email app UIs work when you add / remove addresses, that's the effect i'm trying to implement. Achieving this effect using constraints, though, is eluding me. Any help would greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the view controller code, including code that processes the collection view cell addition / deletion, but I doubt that that would help. I just laid out the controls in IB and chose "Add all missing constraints". When I add / remove cells to / from the collection view, I want it to resize to fit its content and have the other controls move up / down automatically, but all of the documentation i've read so far on constraints deals with positioning rather than resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

1. removed all constraints in IB
2. added a height constraint on the collection view and connected it to an IBOutlet
3. had IB add missing constraints
4. add an observer for the collection view's contentSize property

Now, when I add a cell to the collection view and tell it to reload, i'm notified when the contentSize changes and can set the constant for the height constraint to the contentSize height. Result: a collection view that resizes to fill it's content, with the other controls moving up / down as needed :-)